# prometheus alertname regex

Tags: regex, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

i trey to have all Disk alert grom prometheux alert manager so i put this code on config.yml,

my code is:

```
route:
  receiver: rocketchat
  group_wait: 30s
  group_interval: 5m
  repeat_interval: 3h
  group_by: ['alertname']
  routes:

  - match:
      severity: critical
       env:internal
       alertname:'*.Disk.*'
    receiver: rocketchat
    continue: true
```

i don'tknow why that not work, thanks for any help.

Comment: isnt that a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66851661/prometheus-alertname-multiple-regex

Answer (score 2):

Try the following configuration:

```
  routes:
    - receiver: 'rocketchat'
      match_re:
        alertname: ".*Disk.*"
        env: internal
        severity: critical
```

Comment: that works but if i have two match like :     - receiver: 'rocketchat2'
    match_re:
      alertname: ".*Disk.*"
      env: internal
      severity: critical

  - receiver: 'rocketchat2'
    match_re:
      alertname: ".*Memory.*"
      env: internal
      severity: critical           that not work

Comment: If the answer worked could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
routes:
  - match:
      severity: critical
    receiver: email
    continue: true

  - match:
      severity: critical
    receiver: rocketchat
    continue: true

  - receiver: 'rocketchat2'
    match_re:
      alertname: ".*Memory.*"
#      env: internal
      severity: critical
      continue: true
```